# Nodejs - passing commander arguments to forever-monitor child process

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, child-process, node-commander, forever-monitor

I have this node cli script

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const path = require('path');
const forever = require('forever-monitor');
const script = path.format({dir: __dirname, base: 'pager.js'});
const chalk = require('chalk');
const commander = require('commander');

commander.version('1.0.0')
.option('-m, --message', 'set awesome message')
.parse();

const args = commander.opts();

const header = `
+---------------------+  
| Awesome v1.0 |
+---------------------+
`;

const child = new (forever.Monitor)(script, {
    max: 2,
    silent: false,
    args: args
});

child.start();

child.on('start', (process) => {
    console.log(chalk.magenta.bold(header));
});

child.on('restart', () => {
    console.log(`Forever restarting script for ${child.times} time`);
});

child.on('exit:code', (code) => {
    console.log(`Forever detected script exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

I want to integrate [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js) togive the user the ability to pass arguments that will be parsed and then passed to the child process that is running until terminal is closed with the help of [forever-monitor](https://github.com/foreversd/forever-monitor) npm package. At the moment I've tried to use commander inside the child process but without success, it will be ignored. I've then moved it inside my `index.js` code but I don't know how to pass the arguments to the child process. At the moment I get this error if I pass the parsed arguments to the `args` option of forever monitor

```
host:awesome dev$ node . -m 'Hello!'
/Users/dev/Desktop/awesome/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/forever-monitor/monitor.js:130
    this.args.unshift(script);
              ^

TypeError: this.args.unshift is not a function
    at new exports.Monitor (/Users/dev/Desktop/awesome/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/forever-monitor/monitor.js:130:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dev/Desktop/awesome/index.js:20:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Can anyone give me some help about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forever-monitor: the `args` configuration option passed to `forever-monitor` expects an array.

```
'args':    ['foo','bar']
```

Commander: `program.opts()` returns a regular javascript object which is a hash with the keys being the option names. `program.args` is an array of the parsed command-arguments with recognised options and option-values removed.

In Commander, also have a look at `.allowUnknownOption()` and `passThroughOptions()` so Commander allows unrecognised options on the command line. The default behaviour is to show an error for unrecognised options.

Comment: So I need to pass `program.args` to the `args` field of forever-monitor then in the child process I need to use process.argv to get them right?

Comment: Yes, I think so